# xsl: How to select the first x number of characters in a node?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following node in a XML doc:

```
<node>This is some text.</node>
```

I want to select the first 10 characters of the text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the substring function to select the first 10 characters.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(node/text(),1,10)"/>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
substring(/node,1,10)
```

[Reference](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring.html) for substring fn.

Comment: +1 Is better not to rely on text nodes but string value, especially with a mixed content schema.