# Limit XSLT Variable to single character

Tags: xml, xslt

Still trying to understand XML & XSLT at the moment. I'm trying to limit the output that the XSLT is getting from the XML, i've seen similar questions but the solutions do not work for this and i am unsure why.

So i have my XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(NUMBER,'000000')"/>
```

My XML:

```
<NUM>
    <NUMBER>1000</NUMBER>
</NUM>

<NUM>
    <NUMBER>2000</NUMBER>
</NUM>

<NUM>
    <NUMBER>3000</NUMBER>
</NUM>
```

The code outputs all three "1000", "2000" & "3000", Which is what i get, all above works fine, what i want to change is that the output will be "1", "2" & "3" So i want to say in the code that it will only take the first number from "NUMBER" so the first number of 1000 which would be 1, then 2 from 2000 and 3 from 3000.

I have tried this [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874701/xsl-how-to-select-the-first-x-number-of-characters-in-a-node) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why does `<xsl:value-of select="substring(NUMBER, 1, 1)"/>` not work for you? Explain which result you want and which one you get.

Comment: The question is not well-defined. Do you always want the first digit of the number, or the thousands digit, or something else?

Comment: The code outputs all three "1000", "2000" & "3000", Which is what i get, all above works fine, what i want to cahnge is that the output will be "1", "2" & "3"

So i want to say in the code that it will only take the first number from "NUMBER" so the first number of 1000 which would be 1, then 2 from 2000 and 3 from 3000.

Comment: I tried "select="format-number(NUMBER, 1,1)"/>" but it wouldn't process through x-trans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment I think all you need is `<xsl:value-of select="substring(NUMBER, 1, 1)"/>`.